# Analytics data from google.com?

Tags: statistics

While browsing around for browser statistics today I figured that it would be nice to see a dataset from www.google.com, it ought to be somewhat well balanced and should provide a pretty decent "general" cut of the netizen population. However, googling (oh, the irony) for a while I couldn't find any such public datasets available.

Is any data like this (from Google specifically) available, either for free or subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

But there are global stats offered by statistics companies that should give you the same information you;re looking for. [Net Applications](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/report.aspx?qprid=0) and [statcounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/) are two commonly cited in the press.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks for confirming. I do know about both of the sources you mentioned, but thanks anyway!